What should I do if I receive an email asking for minor corrections in a manuscript, with no reviewer comments?
I have received a mail yesterday saying that I should do some minor corrections in my manuscript, but there are no reviewer comments included. How should I proceed in this case?

I'm not sure what you mean by "same.thing" are you referring to another question?

contact the editor

What should you do?  Be happy!  Your paper was not desk-rejected! ... It is not the responsibility of paper referees to find errors in your paper: that is your responsibility.

@GEdgar It would be still nice to have a pointer what to look at. There could be a remark such as an exemplary number of grammar errors and stating that there are more.

@GEdgar Even if the referees approve the manuscript as it is, OP should have received their comments stating that. If it got minor revision the authors should be made aware of what led to this outcome and what they should fix.

Why the downvotes?

@DavidRaveh they are "legacy" downvotes, look at the edit history and you will understand.

There are two obvious things that might have happened here. Neither are things to worry about.

The reviewer comments are on an online manuscript management portal. You need to log in, probably to the same place to submitted the manuscript and check there.

The editor simply forgot to attach the comments. People forget to include attachments all the time.


Having double checked you definitely haven't missed the comments on an online portal, I'd simply write a polite email to the editor in question, thanking them for their time handling the manuscript, saying you are more than happy to make the corrections, but that you can't find the reviewer comments anywhere and could they please point you in the correct direction.

2b. The editor did not notice that the reviewer wrote their report in the box titled "Comments to the editor" instead of the one titled "Comments to the author". As a result the reviewer's comments are not automatically appended to the email.
